# Manipulate DOM onClick in NextJs SSR

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to run a simple DOM script on NextJS with SSR.
I know that the DOM isn't available with SSR and I am receiving an undefined error on the variable "menu"

Just wondering if someone can clear this up as to how I would do this using hooks? I am new to React and NextJS and still don't fully grasp hooks.

```
<div className={styles.menuCon} onClick={menu()} >
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

```
function menu() {
  var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
  menu.style.width="400px";
  menu.style.height="400px";

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<div className={styles.menuCon} onClick={menu} >
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

```
function menu(event) {
  let menu = event.currentTarget;
  menu.style.width="400px";
  menu.style.height="400px";
 }
```